# Which icon to use for "do not crawl this page"

Tags: icon

In a new prototype, I need an icon to show "Do not Crawl this page"

The purpose of the icon is :

- The users are able to choose which pages the search engines should *not* crawl.

I created an icon consisting of a page, a search icon over it, and a line over all of them.
The Icon appears too busy.

Does any one have a solution?

Update: some one asked for screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot?

Comment: i have added screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally a **spider** is used to designate a web crawler.

[image]

I would use a spider icon, then a spider icon with a "don't" symbol over it.

Spider icon from here: [**Iconfinder**](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/559717/bot_google_bot_internet_seo_spider_web_web_crawler_icon)

Comment: spider do work, but it is so technical. i need something that anyone understand.

Comment: Is it technical? It's like stating the magnifying glass is too technical for search... it's pretty much universally understood for anyone controlling web content. Sometimes the best solution is to educate uneducated users, not reinvent the wheel. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
the users are editors with no idea of how search crawlers and search engines work.
that is why i afraid a crawl would be a little too technical for them.
I hope i get another suggestion

Comment: @Fawad as Metis said, the spider is the only thing I've ever seen used to reference web crawling.  You say it's too technical, but I would honestly have no idea what your created icon was trying to portray, without you telling me.  The spider is simple, effective, universally recognized.

Comment: @Fawad then how do they understand the purpose of the icon no matter what it is?

Comment: @fawad if they know the `crawl` concept they also know the `spider` one?

Comment: @Manly, yes you are right. The icon i created was not clear at all. once could not know that it has something to do with the purpose

Comment: I have not experienced the spider icon and would not know what it is saying. Common "Do Not" symbols are a large X, a cross out sign or a stop sign. For "Crawl" I would use an eye or a magnifying glass or an icon of a crawling person. An eye at the top of a pyramid, all behind a cross out symbol would seem to suggest "don't let big brother see" or "don't let google see"

Comment: @Webster thanks for the suggestion. Your suggestion goes in the right direction. write it as answer so that i accept it

Comment: I disagree with the magnifying glass idea.  Crawling (indexing) and searching are not exactly the same thing.  Which one do you want it do mean?  If you intend it to mean "Do not crawl" then I still say spider is the only logical choice.  If you actually mean "Do not _search_" then perhaps the magnifying glass could work. @Fawad

Comment: @Manly your point is absolutely legit, i thinks i should do it textonly. Or maybe a google logo and a red line over it

Comment: Shortly i accepted your answer, but i noticed that the spider icon is used to represent bug.
https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=bug
https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=bug
I could not find any good icon to represent crawl

Comment: Actually a beetle is traditionally a "bug" and a spider is traditionally "crawl:.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [lock](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=lock) or a key, or a combination of the two? With the proper icon pair you can also represent the *unlocked* pages if you need to also show these somehow.

[image]

Comment: That would look like Lock page not Hide page.

Comment: A lock would mean protected page (For users)